# Simplifying $\textrm{sinc}( \textrm{acos}(\cdot) )$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Geometry is not my strong point - I'm trying to clean up some equations from a paper and ended up with this mess.

$$ \textrm{sinc} \left[ \textrm{acos} \left( \frac{p_{x}}  {\sqrt{p_x^2 + p_y^2 + p_z^2}} \right) \right] \\ $$

I've never really came across sinc before.

$$ \textrm{sinc}(\theta) = \frac{ \sin(\theta)} {\theta} $$

It's come from substituting the angle with vectors to generalise the equation.

where theta is the angle between point vector p and the origin

$$ p=(p_x, p_y, p_z) $$

giving

$$ \theta = \textrm{acos} \left( \frac{p_{x}}  {\sqrt{p_x^2 + p_y^2 + p_z^2}} \right)  \\ $$

Can this be simplified without ending up with the same mess in the denominator?

Comment: Please can you add more context? Where is this equation from? What do the variables represent? What do you hope to achieve by simplifying the equation? What have you tried?

Comment: sorry pressed post instead of preview - is that better?

Comment: I'm puzzled by the appearance of $\operatorname{sinc}$ in this context, but either way you'll probably find useful the identity $\sin \arccos x = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ (to see why it works, draw a right triangle with leg $x$ and hypotenuse $1$).

Comment: Incidentally, your expression $\theta = \operatorname{arccos}(\cdots)$ is the angle between $p$ and the positive part of the $x$-axis.

Comment: its an approximation of the directivity function for a transducer which is dependant on the incidence angle, $ \theta $

Answer (score 3):

In general, if

$$ \theta=\arccos\left(\frac{a}{|b|}\right) $$

then

$$ \sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}{|b|} $$

In this case,

$$ \theta=\arccos\left(\frac{p_x}{|p|}\right) $$

so

$$ \sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt{p_y^2+p_z^2}}{|p|} $$

thus

$$ \textrm{sinc}\ \theta=\frac{\sqrt{p_y^2+p_z^2}}{\theta|p|} $$

[image: triangle]